# How to print to printer connected to Windows 7 PC from iPad Air?

Tags: ipad, windows

I see the answer for printing from an iPad to a Windows enterprise, but I just want to print from an iPad Air to my home printer (HP Officejet Pro L7590) that is running on my network from a Windows desktop.  Is there a solution simpler than Presto?

Answer (score 1):

The L7590 does not provide Airprint capabilities and can 't be added.

If you run Windows you can try to enable AirPrint - like described here *(I haven't tried it my self, because I'm running OS X, so I can't comment on how good it is)*: http://www.airprintactivation.com/ - then the printer(s) setup on your PC will be available in iOS

If you run OS X you can download a more less free AirPrint enabler: http://www.netputing.com/handyprint/ - then the printer(s) setup on your Mac will be available in iOS

Answer (score 0):

The HP Officejet Pro L7590 is not AirPrint enabled, however you can print to it using the [HP ePrint](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Officejet-Pro-L7000-All-in-One-Printer-series/2511708/model/3643610/document/c02775166) app.